# Will str(float(s)) == s

Tags: python

Will `str(float(s)) == s` if `s` contains a valid floating point string? (Ignoring whitespace and other complications)

Background:

I have a text box where the user enters a floating point number. I store the number as a `float`, maybe writing it to a file and retrieving it later. If I write the value back to the text box, without changing it, I want it to be exactly as before.

I don't want floating point "precision" errors such as the classic `0.3 - 0.1 = 0.1999999....`.  Does that only occur after doing a floating point operation, or can it happen to a float which was entered as a decimal string?

Edit:
I don't care about loss of precision e.g. `str(float("1.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999"))`, or losing exponents eg `str(float("1e3"))`, or formatting stuff like `str(float("1"))=="1.0"`. I just want to check whether sensible values like `str(float("0.1"))` could ever come back as weird values which would confuse a user.

Comment: sometimes, probably

Comment: In the general case, no. For example: `str(float('0.33233132132332131111'))`

Comment: Right now you are trying to work around a complex subject by hacking together a semi-adequate solution. I say semi-adequate because even if it works, you don't understand why it works, and therefore can't effectively maintain it. Instead of doing that, I suggest learning about how floats work.

Comment: In some cases, no, because `>>> str(float('1.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999'))` gives you `'2.0'` (that number can't be represented anyway).

Comment: An integer string is a valid argument to `float` and your statement would not be true, `str(float('1')) != '1'` for example. Not sure if that meets your conditions though

Comment: If it is loss of precision that matters to you, use `decimal.Decimal`. `str(decimal.Decimal('1.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999')) == '1.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999'`. But if you need to preserve a non-canonical representation like `1.20`, store it as a string, not as a number.

Comment: If you want to guarantee that the string representation won’t change, the best way to do that is to store the data as a string.  If you can’t do that for some reason, an alternative approach would be to convert to float and back as soon as the user presses enter, so at least the user can see up-front how the string changed.

Comment: you might be interested in using the [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) class for remove those precision problems `Decimal("0.3") - Decimal("0.1") == Decimal('0.2') `

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, I know how floats work, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: Now your question is just inconsistent. Please fix

Answer (score 2):

No.

Consider, for example, `1.2e10`.

```py
>>> str(float("1.2e10")) 
'12000000000.0'
```

Or,

```py
>>> str(float("1.20000000000000000000000")) 
'1.2'
```

This is due to differences in the way python parses and prints floats. When parsing a float, it must understand a wide variety of values, such as scientific notation. However, the code for turning this float into a string has zero knowledge of how it was originally written to the python program; and will write out the number in it's own 'ideal' way.

> I don't want floating point "precision" errors such as the classic 0.3 - 0.1 = 0.1999999..... Does that only occur after doing a floating point operation, or can it happen to a float which was entered as a decimal string?

Unless you're working on highly sensitive software, you won't need to worry about this. Floating-point (and especially 64-bit floating point) are very precise, and an inputted value (such as 1.2345678910111213) will always be 'close enough' unless you're working with more than *fourteen digits* (a lot).

**TL;DR:** Unless you can guarantee `s` came from `str`, you cannot guarantee that `str(float(s))` will equal `s`. Nonetheless, you probably won't be needing to check such a thing anyways, as floating point numbers are almost always 'good enough'.